# How to import own textures

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just started with c# and unity (been a VBA and Java Developer) and have a simple question.

When i draw a background, a character or something else in 2d in gimp with my wacom. Is it possible to easily import those in unity and use them there for a 2d platformer?

Thanks!

Comment: Please note StackOverflow is a programming question site. Anyway what you're looking for is [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ImportingAssets.html) and the answer is yes: just copy-paste your assets and they will be imported (then you can tweak your import settings).

Comment: Hi Nico, For the sake of closing this question. Can you accept my answer or tell me why it is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple. You can usually import an asset by simply dragging it into the editor. 
See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ImportingAssets.html